# vaex apply does not work when using dataframe columns

Tags: python, vaex

I am trying to tokenize natural language for the first sentence in wikipedia in order to find 'is a' patterns. n-grams of the tokens and left over text would be the next step. "Wellington is a town in the UK." becomes "`town` is a `attr_root` in the `country`." Then find common patterns using n-grams.

For this I need to replace string values in a string column using other string columns in the dataframe. In Pandas I can do this using

```
df['Test'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'].replace(x['Rep'], x['Sub']), axis=1)
```

but I cannot find the equivalent `vaex` method. [This](https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/442) issue led me to believe that this should be possible in `vaex` based on Maarten Breddels' example code, however when trying it I get the below error.

```
import pandas as pd
import vaex

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": [
            "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",
            "Allen, Mr. William Henry",
            "Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth",
        ],
        "Rep": ["Braund", "Henry", "Miss."],
        "Sub": ["<surname>", "<name>", "<title>"],
    }
)
dfv = vaex.from_pandas(df)

def func(x, y, z):
    return x.replace(y, z)

dfv['Test'] = dfv.apply(func, arguments=[df.Name.astype('str'), df.Rep.astype('str'), df.Sub.astype('str')])
```

Gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\vaex\dataframe.py", line 455, in apply
    arguments = _ensure_strings_from_expressions(arguments)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\vaex\utils.py", line 780, in _ensure_strings_from_expressions
    return [_ensure_strings_from_expressions(k) for k in expressions]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\vaex\utils.py", line 780, in <listcomp>
    return [_ensure_strings_from_expressions(k) for k in expressions]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\vaex\utils.py", line 782, in _ensure_strings_from_expressions
    return _ensure_string_from_expression(expressions)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\vaex\utils.py", line 775, in _ensure_string_from_expression
    raise ValueError('%r is not of string or Expression type, but %r' % (expression, type(expression)))
ValueError: 0     Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
1    Allen, Mr. William Henry
2    Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth
Name: Name, dtype: object is not of string or Expression type, but <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

How can I accomplish this in `vaex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a bug. Needed `dfv` in the call to `apply` instead of `df`.

Also got this faster method from the nice people at `vaex`.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
import vaex

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": [
            "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",
            "Allen, Mr. William Henry",
            "Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth",
        ],
        "Rep": ["Braund", "Henry", "Miss."],
        "Sub": ["<surname>", "<name>", "<title>"],
    }
)
dfv = vaex.from_pandas(df)


@vaex.register_function()
def replacer(x, y, z):
    res = []
    for i, j, k in zip(x.tolist(), y.tolist(), z.tolist()):
        res.append(i.replace(j, k))
    return pa.array(res)

dfv['Test'] = dfv.func.replacer(dfv['Name'], dfv['Rep'], dfv['Sub'])
```